# React Invariant Violation addComponentAsRefTo

Tags: reactjs

Today I started seeing a bunch of this error on my Jest unit tests on a bunch of different components in my local environment:

> Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).

According to the link it's likely a duplicate copy of React. I took the advice in the link and did an `npm ls react` and got the following result:

```
my-project@1.0.1 /Users/wogsland/Projects/my-project
└── react@15.4.2
```

But the tests all pass with flying colors on our CI tool with the same version of the codebase, so I'm pretty sure that it's the duplicate issue.

Any advice on where I can find the duplication?

Comment: It's not in the build chain, because the tests use the raw files.